# My UPDATE statement does not work, but DELETE and INSERT does

Tags: javascript, sql

I am using sql with Javascript to make a simple CRUD project, but when i need to update a user from de DB I get an error saying: "could not prepare statement (1 no such column: (new name))", so I ended up using a DELETE and INSERT instead, but the UPDATE statement is better in terms of time, so I'd like to use the UPDATE.

```
//modal
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Editar persona</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Nombre</legend>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nom">
                        <legend>Apellido</legend>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ape">        
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Actualizar datos</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

//table
<table style="margin: 30px;" class="table table-bordered" id="tabla">
    <thead align="center" class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
            <th scope="col">Apellido</th>
            <th scope="col">Opciones</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

//table rows
$('#tabla').append(
                    `<tr id="${id}">
                         <td>${id}</td>
                         <td>${nombre}</td>
                         <td>${apellido}</td>
                         <td align="center">
                             <button type="button" style="margin-right: 10px" data-toggle="modal" data- 
                              target="#modal" class="btn btn-outline-info">Editar</button>
                             <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Eliminar</button></td>
                     </tr>`

//update function
let tabla = document.getElementById("tabla")
tabla.addEventListener("click", e => {
if( e.target.className == "btn btn-outline-info"){
            let idBuscado = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.id
            let modal = document.getElementById("modal");
            modal.addEventListener("click", e => {
                if ( e.target.className == "btn btn-primary"){
                    let nomN = document.getElementById('nom').value
                    let apeN = document.getElementById('ape').value
                    db.transaction(function(tx){
                        //let sql = 'UPDATE PERSONA SET nombre= '+nomN+', apellido='+apeN+' WHERE id = '+idBuscado+''
                        let sqlD = 'DELETE FROM PERSONA WHERE id = '+idBuscado+''
                        let sqlU = 'INSERT INTO PERSONA (id, nombre, apellido) VALUES(?,?,?)'
                        tx.executeSql(sql, [],() => void 0, (tx, err) => console.log(err.message))
                        tx.executeSql(sqlU, [idBuscado, nomN, apeN],() => alert("Se ha actualizado la persona con éxito"), (tx, err) => console.log(err.message))
                    })
                }
                
            })

}
```

Comment: Learn to use parameters!  This will fix most of your problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error messsage is about that there's no `name` column in that table. It means that you are probably set the `nombre`'s value as `name`, but not qouting it, so you're ending up with the query:

```
UPDATE PERSONA SET nombre=name,...
```

**Change this**

```
let sql = 'UPDATE PERSONA SET nombre= '+nomN+', apellido='+apeN+' WHERE id = '+idBuscado+''
```

**To**

```
let sql = 'UPDATE PERSONA SET nombre="'+nomN+'", apellido="'+apeN+'" WHERE id="'+idBuscado+'"'
```

### Warning

Please keep in mind that this is dangerous and always use prepared statements!

> Using string concatenation to get values into SQL queries is error
> prone and might make the program vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.
> Always using parameterized queries is the right thing to do.

Comment: Don't promote using string concatenation to get values into SQL queries. That's error prone and might make the program vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Always using parameterized queries is the right thing to do.

Comment: I agree, but an answer to the question is not promoting in my eyes.

Comment: Oh yes it is. The right solution to solve the problem would be parameterized queries. But as you can see the OP opted to accept the wrong because very dangerous solution. And that also signals to others, who may come across that question/answer, that this is the right thing to do.

Comment: The dangerous practice is in the question, and that's the promoting. The answer is good for the question itself as it's error handling problem. However, I updated my answer with a warning, so others will know about it.

Comment: Your answer is confusing. "always use prepared statements!", but your answer isn't using prepared statements? So it's not always?

Comment: Please read the comments above and the question as well. I answered why the code in the question not works. It's not about the security, coding style, lack of testing or anything else. The warning can be useful for the beginners who don't know about that.